# Out of memory error when using '.*' operation in Matlab

Tags: matlab, out-of-memory

Below is the code I used in my m.file:

```
for idx = i_start:i_end
    CheckTemp = (timeTick > time_tr(idx)) .* (timeTick <= time_tr(idx));
    CheckTemp2 = find(CheckTemp);
    IdxS = min(CheckTemp2);
    IdxE = max(CheckTemp2);
    ......
```

the `timeTick` array is a double array about **100MB**, and `idx` is from about **2000** to **4000**. Cause I check the m-file step by step, I find that before the loop, my memroy commit charge is: **817M/5422M**. There is a lot of free space, right?

But my Matlab v6.5 told me that: `Error in '.*', out of memory`... which makes me really confused.

Plus, I executed the code line by line before. And no error occurred. I really don't know why. I hope there is someone who can help...

**If you need anymore information, please comment.**

Comment: Is time_tick a sorted array? If so, there is a better implementation possible which requires less memory.

Comment: Is time_tr(idx) a single scalar? I'm confused, won't CheckTemp always be an array of zeros since timeTick can't both be > time_tr(idx) and <= time_tr(idx) ?!?

Comment: are time_tr and timeTick sorted? If so, this could be done much more efficiently with a single pass through the arrays

Comment: There's no need to allocate *any* arrays of the same huge size as timeTick, which is what's implicitly done with `.*`, `>`, and `<=` commands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `timeTick` and `timeTr` are sorted, this can be done:

1. *Without* creating additional arrays of the same huge size as `timeTick`
2. With a single pass through the two arrays `timeTick` and `timeTr`
3. In about 0.29 seconds in Matlab 2015b on a 150MB double array timeTick and 2000 entry array timeTr using the code below (on my computer).

The code would go as follows (note you must set `time_tr(end+1) = inf` for my code to work).

```
%This code requires last entry of time_tr to be inf, eg. time_tr(end+1)=inf;
n_tick = length(timeTick);
n_tr   = length(time_tr);

IdxS = NaN(n_tr, 1);
IdxE = NaN(n_tr, 1);

i_tick = 1;
i_tr   = 1;

window_start_i_tick = 1; 
window_end    = time_tr(1);

while(i_tick <= n_tick)
   t = timeTick(i_tick);
   if(t > window_end)
      IdxS(i_tr) = window_start_i_tick;
      IdxE(i_tr) = i_tick - 1;

      window_start_i_tick = i_tick;

      i_tr = i_tr + 1;
      while(t > time_tr(i_tr)) %take care of case that we skip past a window/windows
          i_tr = i_tr + 1;
      end

      window_end = time_tr(i_tr);        
   end    
   i_tick = i_tick + 1;
end
IdxS(i_tr) = window_start_i_tick;
IdxE(i_tr) = i_tick;
```

Answer (score 2):

The MATLAB [memory management page](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/resolving-out-of-memory-errors.html) has some useful information such as the process memory limit on your system. In general, it is a good idea to run `clear all` before running a memory-intensive operation. Since, as Daniel pointed out, MATLAB's ability to allocate arrays is based on contiguous available memory, and `clear` does not guarantee garbage collection, it may be a good idea to restart MATLAB, espeially on older versions.

On a side note, I suspect that you will find that `CheckTemp = (timeTick > time_tr(idx)) .* (timeTick <= time_tr(idx));` will always give you an array of `logical` zeros. `.*` Acts like binary `&` on arrays of logicals and you are guaranteeing that there will be no overlap by comparing `>` in one case and `<=` in the other. Perhaps you meant to use something like `time_tr(idx-1)` for one of the indices?

Comment: yes, thank you for your side note...it should be: (timeTick > time_tr(idx)) .* (timeTick <= time_tr(idx+1))

Answer (score 0):

Reading the documentation for `memory` you will notice that the continuous available address space is the limit. Your Matlab version can not use your full memory, it is limited to a 32 bit addresses space.

I recommend to switch to a recent 64 bit version of matlab or to octave which is a open source clone.

Comment: Using the same windows system and same computer, I perform the above code, and it worked well. So I really don't think switching to 64bit will solve the problem...

Comment: I mean perform the code line by line, not in the m.file...So that make me confused.

Comment: Opps, I misunderstanded...sorry, and thank you for your comment...but still I will try to figure out the reason.

Comment: @Saji to my experience the amount of available continuous address space is totally unpredictable on Windows systems. Running the most file several times, restarting Matlab in between, will probably results in some successful and some failed runs.

Comment: You're absolutely right, Daniel...I try the my code several times, once successed, and other times failed.